# Erlang create directory

Tags: erlang, directory

I need create subdirectory in specific directory.

In erlang docs i find only file:make_dir/1 which create dir in the project source dir. How can i create directory in other dir?

**I find solution. Maybe it will be interesting somebody:**

```
filelib:ensure_dir("/this/path/will/soon/exist/").
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can ensure that a directory exists (and create it if it doesn't, which is what you're looking for) using `filelib:ensure_dir`.

Example:

```
filelib:ensure_dir("/this/path/will/soon/exist/")
```

References:

- [filelib:ensure_dir](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/filelib.html#ensure_dir-1) documentation

Comment: Not sure if the '/' bug is still there but make sure you add a slash in the end of your path otherwise it won't work (at least this was the case in older versions).

Comment: @Mazen Harake: Added it to the answer just to be safe.

Comment: I don't think that the trailing "/" is a bug.  The documentation says that it creates the parent directories for the "specified file or directory name", so if you pass "/this/path/will/soon/exist" then it assumes that "exist" is the file name, and will only create the parent directories up to "soon", leaving it to you to create the file "exist" subsequently.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation must have been unclear as you can use `file:make_dir/1` to create any directory which you would normally be allowed to create. It does **not** create all directories in the path, this you have to do explicitly yourself.

Using `filelib:ensure_dir/1` with a path terminated by `"/"` is not documented but it is explicitly handled in the code so I doubt that it will go away.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a subdirectory and confirm or create any parent directories needed

```
make_dir(Dir) ->
  % create or confirm the parent Dir exists (works recursively)
  ok = filelib:ensure_dir(Dir),
  % create or confirm Dir exists
  case file:make_dir(Dir) of
    ok -> ok;
    {error, eexist} -> ok;
    {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
  end.
```